# If there are.... then I would like

Tags: grammar

It is correct to write : "If there are tickets available, I would like to buy it one?"

And, in case is correct, what type of conditional would be?

Comment: What do you mean by what type of conditional?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to say is: "If there are tickets available, I would like to buy one."

Alternatively: "If there is a ticket available, I would like to buy it."

The pronoun must match the ticket in the earlier part of the sentence that it is referring to.